# How to handle customer specific requirements to a generic C# code base?

Tags: c#

Assuming you have a new product, lets consider what it does to be the base implementation, which you have deployed in a SaaS form for a couple of customers.

Along come a new customer and they say "love it, but I need it do a,b,c".  Ideally you don't want to add if statements into existing functions that handle the specifics for the new customer, because after six new customers the code is a mess.  You don't want different deployments from different branches, because that'll be an admin nightmare and changes to base being merged to different branches is time consuming.

So how do you have a single code branch that has all customer customisation in it (all be it I suspect in different classes, partial classes or something) and built and deployed with them all, but depending on the customer that is logged in uses their customisations if they exist?

I've started looking at IoC (Ninject), but not sure yet if that is what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance

PS - not that I think it is likely to have an influence on the answer, but this is a .NET 6 EF Core Web Server solution

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about Feature Flags https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core?tabs=core5x

It is basically `if` statements but more structured and controllable per customer.

Comment: I'm not sure it is, this sounds like conditional building?  As this is a SaaS product with many customers it would include all their customisations, but at run time dependent upon user use different version so methods, but hopefully without a million if statements

Comment: Do you want to maintain one build/release process for each client, or one build/release process for all clients?  I know which I'd choose.

Comment: As a SaaS system, there will be multiple clients using a single deployment

Comment: OK, so feature flags, with a tenant based configuration sounds like what you are looking for.